# Lost wifi somehow. Keep getting "nl80211 not found"

Tags: wifi, wlan

I have one of these little boards called a C.H.I.P. by a company called Next Thing. They went bankrupt. It's kind of like Raspberry Pi. It was $10, has some gpio pins, runs Linux, etc. I can reflash it if I have to, but that's a lot of craziness I'd like to avoid.

It seems I've done something that's disabled the WiFi and I'd like to get it running again. I have no idea what I did that disabled it. I don't recall doing anything with the networking. Just turned it on one day and the wifi won't come up.

I can't figure out how to get it turned back on and was hoping someone could help. The one sort of recurring symptom I see, is that a lot of things I do will give me "`nl80211 not found`". For example, if I type `iw wlan0 info`. If I type `ifup wlan0` it runs without an error or any message, but if I do `ifconfig`, the only adapters I see are `lo` and `usb0`.

Trying to run `hostapd /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf` gives me:

```
nl80211: 'nl80211' generic netlink not found
Failed to initialize driver 'nl80211'
```

I've googled a lot around the messages I've run into. I can't find anything that really tells me how to fix the problem, or at least nothing that's worked for me so far.

Like I said, worst case scenario, I can reflash it, but that would be a huge hassle and I'd rather not go through it if possible. My hope is someone can help me diagnose and fix the problem.

I guess what I need to know is what is it that makes Linux aware of wlan0, because that seems to be what I'm missing. I added

`iface wlan0 inet manual` to the `/etc/network/interfaces` file, but that didn't fix it, so I removed it.

That seems to affect whether or not ifup/ifdown will accept 'wlan0', so maybe it should be there. I don't know. I just don't really know the lower level networking stuff in Linux.

I'm not sure what else I can offer. Results of `ifconfig -a`...

```
root@chip1:/etc# ifconfig -a
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1088 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1088 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
          RX bytes:88128 (86.0 KiB)  TX bytes:88128 (86.0 KiB)

sit0      Link encap:IPv6-in-IPv4
          NOARP  MTU:1480  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

usb0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr be:e8:12:79:eb:8a
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

**Update:**
I just remembered that the wifi stuff is configured through something called NetworkManager. I've never used it before. It is configured how I want it. Here's the wifi config from that:

```
[connection]
id=NNNN
uuid=513a7169-39bd-4493-b2ba-22028e86aaec
interface-name=wlan0
type=wifi

[wifi]
ssid=NNNN
mode=infrastructure

[ipv6]
method=auto

[ipv4]
method=auto
dns=10.95.153.131;
address1=10.95.153.185/24,10.95.153.131
may-fail=false
```

Comment: Maybe your interface is down and your device is abstracted in another name. When you enter `ifconfig` without any option, it only shows up interfaces as default.
Enter `ifconfig -a` that shows all of devices even they're down. Then make it up using `ifconfig yourinterface up`.

Comment: "ifconfig wlan0 up"  gives: "wlan0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device
". ifconfig -a shows: lo (Link encap:Local Loopback), sit0 (Link encap:IPv6-in-IPv4), and usb0 (Link encap:Ethernet)

Comment: So I think it should be a low-level problem. I mean problem in HAL or there's a problem with required modules for your device, maybe a physical problem.

Comment: perhaps. My hope was that someone would be able to help me diagnose that.